# append the value to URL

Tags: javascript, php, url, append, location

I have a value inside a script,I want to append this value to URL,I tried with window.location but It is not working

```
function handleSelect1(elm) {
    
   var elm = document.getElementById('hiddencorporateId').value;
    window.location = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + "?updateid=" + elm.value;
    // document.write(elm);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "in PHP"? You post JavaScript. Also never document.write anything after the page has loaded. In fact dont use document.write(ln) at all

Comment: To rewrite a URL, you can do `const url = new URL(location.href); url.searchParams.set("updateid",elm.value); location = url.toString();`

Answer (score -1):

use to update `location.href`

```
function handleSelect1(elm) {
    
   var elm = document.getElementById('hiddencorporateId').value;
   
  location.href = location.href + "?updateid=" + elm
}
```

Comment: What if it already has ?updateid=?

Comment: `window.location` return an **object** and location.href is string to redirect new url

Comment: `https://samle.com/page.xxx?updateid=abc` will redirect to `https://samle.com/page.xxx?updateid=abc?updateid=def` which is an invalid URL - on next click `https://samle.com/page.xxx?updateid=abc?updateid=def?updateid=hij`